# facebook.stackoverflow.com tools show flags on non-Facebook SO questions

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, moderator-tools, mini-site, facebook.stackoverflow

On the Stack Overflow Facebook minisite tools page, flags are shown without tag restrictions, meaning that flags from the main Stack Overflow site on non-Facebook questions are shown.

[screenshot http://phpcode.eu/images/1314216098.png](http://phpcode.eu/images/1314216098.png)

As Bill notes below, this makes sense for moderators, but it doesn't make sense for 10k and 20k users who only use the Facebook sub-site.

Comment: Why do 2 people think this is wrong?

Comment: I can confirm that I'm seeing the same list of flags as well.  That's definitely how it *should* be for diamond moderators, but I don't know about 10k and 20k mods.  I wouldn't want high-rep Facebook.SO users to just start ignoring flags because there were so many non-FB flags displayed.

Comment: yeah I did not add the filtering there ... will have a think

Comment: @waff and will it be added?

Comment: @Popular facebook is capitalised in this case

Comment: @genesis-φ, why? I've never been clear on the official rule for that, so I would really appreciate it if you could point me to a definitive source. I hate it when organization wordmarks don't match the proper spellings....

Comment: @PopularDemand company names are almost always capitalized in English.  For example Facebook's title tag: "Welcome to Facebook - Log In, Sign Up or Learn More"

Comment: @OffBySome - Except for tags, where nothing is capitalized.

Answer (score 5):

Facebook.Stackoverflow needs all the help it can get for closing and flagging the onslaught of bad/dupe/off-topic questions it can get, so these tools should be updated.  It would help to see a focused view on the bad Facebook questions.   It would also benefit any additional future mini-sites that get launched.   This seems like a over sight when this was built and I really hope this gets implemented.  I started a bounty for it to get more attention.

Comment: Gratz! For your 10k