# Difference between "Not Sure" and "Do Not Close" in Review?

Tags: support, review

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [New Feature: Community Review Tasks - Now in Beta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139536/new-feature-community-review-tasks-now-in-beta)

What is the functional difference between "Not Sure" and "Do Not Close" when casting votes in `/review`?  I understand that selecting either will clear the item from my queue, and *not* cast a close vote on it, but is there any other real effect?  For example, does "Do Not Close" automatically add a re-open vote to the question, if it does get closed?

Comment: I believe enough "Do not Close" votes will knock it out of the queue. But "Not Sure" votes just skips it and has no effect. I usually select "Not Sure" if the question is in an area that I'm not familiar with. This is especially the case for dupe votes when I'm not qualified to judge whether or not it really is a dupe.

Comment: According to this post [New Feature: Community Review Tasks - Now in Beta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139536/new-feature-community-review-tasks-now-in-beta) it has no effect.

Answer (score 12):

"Not sure" doesn't do much. It's basically what it sounds like - when you're not sure what action to take or you don't have an opinion on the post you're looking at, click this button and it will skip to the next item in review, if any. It only affects your own view of the queue.

"Do not close" works as follows, as [described by our very own Shog9](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/134673/155160):

> - Voting against closing does not override anyone's close vote. However, a sufficient number of "Do Not Close" responses (currently 5) will kick the question out of the review queue and start aging the close votes - regardless of how many views the question has had.
> - If the question is closed, Do Not Close votes do not translate into re-open votes. However, we may use them to prioritize items in the Reopen Queue (when such a thing exists).

Comment: Ah, good to see "when such a thing exists" regarding the Reopen Queue - that was about to be my next question.  Thanks.

Comment: ...not enough ueue :-)

Answer (score 5):

"Not sure" is effectively a noop bypass. It marks it as reviewed, by you, but does not remove it from the overall review queueueueueueueueueue. The "Do Not Close" one is more interesting. Based on my testing it doesn't change the overall close votes count. I imagine that it will lower its queueueueueueueueueue priority so that it shows up further down the list.

Comment: Reducing it's priority doesn't seem right.  Eventually, if it shouldn't be closed, there should be a way to get it out of the queue entirely, otherwise it will only ever grow in size over time.

Comment: @Servy: Removing it entirely doesn't seem right either since that, effectively, provides a single veto power to all users. BoPerrsson managed to find the actual documentation I was looking for, which says it (unfortunately) drops it from the queueueue.

Comment: @ScottPack I would assume that it is dropped entirely after N votes to not close, where N > 1.  My guess is that it's ~5, but I have no actual evidence of what it is

Comment: @Servy: That wouldn't be entirely unreasonable. The current documentation seems to indicate all it takes is a single vote to drop it from the queue.

Comment: @ScottPack I'm reasonably certain that's not true, as I've seen items in the review queue with more than one votes to not close (just hit back after reviewing some items to see what other's have said).

Comment: @Servy: You're telling me that the official documentation doesn't match what the devs actually did? Lies!

Comment: @ScottPack No, I'm saying the documentation is somewhat vague, and that your interpretation of the (possibly misleading) statement is incorrect.

Comment: @Servy: 2 "Do Not Close" just removes it from the queue right now -- it doesn't affect close votes

Comment: Yes, the post is simply removed from the queue and the close votes start aging [after five "Do not close" votes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139834/what-exactly-happens-with-the-new-do-not-close/139836#139836)

Answer (score 1):

Hitting "Not Sure" only prevents you from seeing that item in the queue, but the item will still be in the queue for others.  I would assume that if there are enough (no idea what "enough" is though) "Do Not Close" votes that it will be removed from the queue entirely (meaning for everyone).