# Reopen Review Queue: Whats the difference between "Leave Closed" and "Skip"?

Tags: support, review, vote-to-reopen

When working through the Reopen Vote review queue, we are presented with a couple of options:

[image: reopen queue options]

What is the difference between the effects of the "Leave Closed" and "Skip" buttons?

When researching this question, I have found a couple of related questions:
[Difference between "Not Sure" and "Do Not Close" in Review?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/145071/273585)
[New Feature: Community Review Tasks - Now in Beta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139536/273585)

These questions suggest that the "Leave Closed" button just gets the question kicked out of the review queue if enough people click on it, and has no effect on the question itself or other users' votes. But they are quite outdated and refer to SE UI elements that have been changed since they were posted. Is this description of the "Leave Closed" button's behavior accurate?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That is only part of the effect of the Leave Closed button. It will kick the question out of review if enough people click it, but it will *also* start the aging process of the existing reopen votes immediately if the review is completed as Leave Closed.

Skip does absolutely nothing. It just moves onto the next review item and prevents that one from appearing for *you* in the future. No action is recorded for it.

Comment: Not sure the last part is correct, since when viewing own reviews, we can see what we skipped. So it is recorded, in some sense.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Well, no public action. It's kind of impossible to not show it to you again without recording something, somewhere.

Answer (score 5):

The "Leave Closed" button is an explicit decision that the post should *not* be reopened. Enough "Leave Closed" votes boots the questions from the reopen queue.

On the other hand, the "Skip" button means "I don't know" and has no effect whatsoever on the question (other than that you won't see it in the reopen queue again, unless it's reenqueued for some reason).