# Allow us to access a post's Reviews directly from the post itself?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, review

Can you give us some way to access pending Reviews for a post from the post itself?

I think this would also help improve the accuracy and quality of reviews done, as users that come across the post naturally are more likely to be better qualified to evaluate the post, and are already taking the time to understand the post's content anyways.

In most cases, these users will be able to provide better reviews than those who are  [often quickly] going through the Review Queues.

In addition, I think it would help get more reviews done, as someone viewing a post through normal site usage would be more likely to take an interest in helping maintain that post. I know I definitely would be more active with this instead of having to go through the massive Review Queue. The task of helping fix one question that I am currently reading is far more do-able than cleaning up a large queue of questions that is largely full of content I don't care about.

I'm thinking of something like a **reviews(1)** link that is accessible from the post itself that appears based on your rep, or perhaps even on your rep within the post's tags.

Comment: Yes! People who come across the question normally are usually more qualified to judge than those who find it in the review queue. (Since the ones in the review queue tend to be a bit... well... hasty...)

Comment: And I would finally gain badges from taking actions in the review system instead just on the question itself :)

Comment: IIRC, the mods can.

Comment: @jokerdino They can, but it's not very user-friendly; it would probably need to be redone if it's going to be exposed to more users

Comment: Why go to the review queue at all? A "leave open" button on the question seems like a good short-circuit.

Comment: @GeorgeWBush I think this would be useful for other review queues in addition to the Reopen and Close queues, such as low quality, first posts, late answers, etc. In addition, it's more work to add code specific to each queue then it is to just add a link to the existing review pages, and you won't have to duplicate any changes made to the review system later on (such as adding additional queue types)

Comment: I wouldn't mind if "Leave Open" button was added to close dialog, especially if this button would have an explanation that using it simply helps to _dequeue_ the post from CV review "conveyor"

Comment: @gnat I would be fine with that as well, although I still think giving users viewing a post naturally access to it's pending reviews is a way to get better quality reviews :)

Comment: @Rachel I would favor jump-to-review over the additional button too, but I just could not figure a simple and reliable UI to present this

Comment: Is there any way at all to tell WHY a feature request (including this one) was declined?

Answer (score 3):

Leave Open makes little to no sense in the context of someone viewing a post "organically"; its primary purpose is to allow us to determine when a sufficient number of people have examined it and end the review (as well as enable aging for votes).

**It *doesn't* directly do anything to counteract existing votes.**

I explained my rationale for this on the old [Vote Not to Close feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125/how-about-a-vote-not-to-close-option-to-counter-the-vote-to-close/134673#134673); you can also read more here: [Allow voting "Vote to not close" from the question without being in a review](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151476/allow-voting-vote-to-not-close-from-the-question-without-being-in-a-review)

Generalizing this to the rest of the queues, I believe this would be - *at best* - a distraction. If you're looking at a post in the normal fashion, you already have the tools at hand to do just about everything you would need or want to do: answer, comment, vote, edit... Presumably, you're there for a specific reason and don't need any *prompting,* so the /review UI would be a poor replacement for what you already have in front of you.

As an aside, moderators do have access to review items directly from any post - this is primarily for informational purposes, although of course nothing stops them from clicking through on a question and casting, say, a binding Do Not Close vote... Not that this makes much sense, given a moderator *can* actually clear pending close votes. But if you ever have a concern about a question with outstanding votes, don't hesitate to flag for moderator attention and voice it.

Comment: It's not as if we can easily clear votes, it's a rather ugly hack by closing and reopening the question and my impression was that we shouldn't actually do that.

Comment: I didn't say it was *pretty*, but it is *easy*. And it leaves a paper-trail visible to all and sundry, so if you *were* to abuse it, folks would know. I've personally found it useful on occasion to prevent bad migrations.

Comment: **It *doesn't* directly do anything to counteract existing votes.** Please consider putting this very prominently in the review blurb. I for one was under the impression *leaving open* countered a *vote to close* (I guess I should have read that answer of yours). Also, suggested edits count as reviews but are accessible from their related posts, is this what you don't want to generalize?

Comment: Suggested edits are something of a special-case, @Frédéric - because of how they work, a suggested edit will *block* any other edits to a post until it is approved or rejected. So if you're looking at a post and see something that should be fixed, the presence of the suggested edit is important enough to bother you with; I don't believe this is true for any other type of review (at least, among those currently implemented). Note that once a suggested edit *has* been rejected, it's no longer visibly linked to the post (and even approved edits are linked only from the revision history).

Comment: @Shog9, it makes sense, thank you. Do you think we still can make the whole "does not counter close votes" implementation detail more prominent in the review description? For instance, "**Leave Open** if this question should not be closed *(Disclaimer: will not actually affect close votes)*"? ;)

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: I'd rather not bog down the descriptions with too much elaboration on the implementation details of each action; can you think of a scenario where you would have taken a *different* action if you'd known what you know now?

Comment: On the vote itself, no, you have a point. It might be less motivating (but the drones still demotivate me more). I also suspect @Rachel will spend less time browsing the review queue, now that she knows questions that are about to be closed will most probably be closed despite her efforts.

Comment: @Frédéric that's not necessarily true. Leave Open isn't *toothless* - it just doesn't do what most folks staring at a question with a pending close vote probably *wish* it did. If someone casts a vote (or even raises a flag) on a question, it *will* be reviewed - but it won't necessarily be closed; Leave Open gives you the ability to say, "I have reviewed this and refrained from voting" - if two other reviewers agree and the question gets no more close votes "organically", then the existing votes will age away. That *does* happen, and although rare it's a fairly important tool.

Comment: @Shog9 I have to disagree with you here. I understand why you'd think it's a distraction, however I think the minor distraction to some users is worth the much needed improvement to the review quality. I'm sure SE could make it be less of a distraction fairly easily as well depending on how they do the UI (make it op-in from the `/review` page, put the `reviews (1)` link in the sidebar, make it rep-based, etc). I'm not asking for a "Leave Open" button on posts containing close votes, but rather a `reviews (X)` link somewhere that will take me to the post's pending reviews.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I'm actually aware that "Leave Open" does not cancel a close vote, it just [moves it one step further towards kicking the question out of the queue](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/151711/158605) :)

Comment: Shouldn't an organic upvote also function as a "leave open" review if the person has the privileges for the review?

Comment: It should, @Ryan. So should editing, answering, voting on answers... This is non-trivial to implement, but I do hope to see it someday.