# Given how well the reopen queue works, should it be easier to close questions

Tags: discussion, review, vote-to-close, closed-questions, vote-to-reopen

The reopen queue seems to be working very well.

Lots of effort has been made in the past to stop questions being closed in error.

If the person that asked a question had a “right of appeal” against the question being put on hold, that added the question to the Reopen Queue, would it then be safe to require fewer votes to close?

Comment: Maybe a reduction from 5 to 4 required close votes?

Comment: No, but only because even the "on hold" silliness doesn't seem to have done much to stem the tide of people complaining about how their post was closed, and I'm not sure I want to see more of that.

Comment: if? Editing your post adds it to the queue. A person doesn't have to make a real and useful edit to do so.

Comment: @KateGregory, but how clear is that to new users.  An appeal button, that then ask the user for the reason of the appeal and added the reason as a comment, would be a lot clearly.     Then people may not feel so bad about closing a question quickly.

Comment: @IanRingrose everyone would just click that. Right now they are getting at least some instruction through comments, or by doing the right thing (editing the question, or providing information in comments that enables others to edit the question) to actually make it openable, or at least move in that direction.

Comment: Not closing questions that need to be closed because they entail complaints isn't a good argument against this, IMO.

Comment: @KateGregory, I expect that at least for duplicates a lot of users are happy to be pointed as the answer and would never appeal.   If the appeal from said “please explain how your questions is different form…” and made them full in the appeal text, it may make it a lot quicker to review, then reviewing questions being closed as duplicates now.

Comment: +1 Something needs to be done about the length of the close queue. This seems like a step in the right direction.

Comment: Related (dupe if this wasn't a [meta-tag:discussion]): [Reduce the number of reviews needed to complete an item in the CV queue](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208563/reduce-the-number-of-reviews-needed-to-complete-an-item-in-the-cv-queue)

Comment: @Pëkka Right, but this request comes across more as saying we don't need to worry about the additional mistakes that might come with fewer votes if we give people a way to easily appeal them, which would presumably be useful for posts that shouldn't have been closed to begin with.

Comment: @Tim but the reopen queue is for questions that have been *edited* since closing, and presumably improved.

Comment: @Pëkka Yeah, but that's not a component of [what he's talking about](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/218504/given-how-well-the-reopen-queue-works-should-it-be-easier-to-close-questions?noredirect=1#comment708961_218504).

Comment: @Tim ohh, I completely misunderstood the request then. I thought it was just about lowering the required number of close votes, which I am very much in favour of, independently from an "appeal" button

Comment: @Pëkka, No the reopen queue is for questions that the system beleave may need to be reopened for some reasion, edits being one, reopen votes being anther, etc

Comment: @Pëkka, The quesions is about doing whatever is needed to enble quesions to be closed quicker with less work, this include making people feal happier about casting close votes, as well as maybe reducing the number of close votes needed.

Comment: @Ian I don't see an "appeal" button working though - I expect *everybody* would appeal the closing of their question. "Hlp why my qst was clozed!!!!!!!! Send codez"

Comment: @Pëkka, An appeal reason like that would be VERY quick for a reviewer to convert into "remain closed" when reviewing the reopen queue.   A **lot quicker** then reviewing the question in the close queue to see if it should be closed..

Comment: But if it's in the reopen queue, someone *other* than the OP thinks that it should be reopened - other community members, or the community bot.   If we swamped the reopen queue with the appeals of the OP's themselves, I expect it would grow to gigantic proportions.

Comment: @Pëkka, An edit however small puts the question into the reopen queue, yet for some reason the queue is not swamped.

Comment: @Pëkka lowering the numer of close votes should make things get through the queue faster instead of growing without bound as it does now.

Comment: @Tim yes, I completely agree. I want the number of required votes lowered to 4... heck, if it were down to me, I'd say 3. I'm just not fond of the "appeal my question's closing" button idea

Comment: Or people should just ask better questions. *flies away*

Comment: I'm thoroughly confused by the comments here. Which are you proposing: an "appeal closure" button, or a lower requirement for close vote count? Or both?

Comment: I really hope something comes of this question. The last 10 times something like this has been suggested have been all but ignored. Actual improvement is long overdue.