# Show close votes on a question from the front page to help reduce the close vote queue

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, stack-overflow, review, vote-to-close

*Idea [one billion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/195355/220332) on how to reduce the close vote queue:*

### Background

Often when I see a question with downvotes I may visit it to see "what’s up" even if I'm not interested in the specific topic in order to offer advice on improving the question or voting to close as appropriate. I find this less exhausting than reviewing from the queue as it has more of a current feel.

However not all questions that need to be closed attract downvotes (primarily duplicates, but others as well on a less frequent basis), these questions do not attract the attention from 3K+ users that they need.

### Proposal

Add details on the front page/tag page as to how many close votes a question has (**viewable by 3k+ users only**) allowing the attention of 3k+ users who may not usually be involved with the review queue to be drawn.

### Reasoning

It has been stated that the hope is to increase the number of people reviewing close votes rather than increase the number of reviews per person. This may draw in review attention from other 3K+ users increasing the number of people involved in review actions rather than leaving the burden on a small number of committed users.

[image]

### Possible "leave open" button addition to the question

As Shog9♦ fairly says attracting only more close attention without attracting more "leave open" attention could lead to easier closure. As a balance to this the "leave open" button from close-vote-review could make an appearance on the question itself. This button would behave the same as the one from the queue: triggering earlier close vote aging, potentially kicking from the queue and once the question is kicked from the close-vote-queue the `[n close vote]` notice being removed from the question.

Comment: Nice idea (+1), would it also be worthwhile for the reason for closing to be stated?

Comment: @UV-D Could be nice, although the reasons could be a bit long

Comment: True, perhaps a code or a shortened summary of the reason?

Comment: Nice idea. But I think adding the reason would be too much visual clutter.

Comment: +1, This seems easier to implement than many other queue-reducing brainstorms, and effective too.

Comment: And it would also tie nicely into [Can we be a bit quicker to close (downvote) questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203830/can-we-be-a-bit-quicker-to-close-downvote-questions)

Comment: I'd prefer **[25% chance this is crap]**

Comment: Regarding "leave open button in the question itself", it was already [suggested and rejected](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/151476/152859). :/

Comment: the problem has been (at last) acknowledged and addresed by SE team: [Enough fuzzying: let's let everything into the close queue and age out questions that don't reach a threshold](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252584/enough-fuzzying-lets-let-everything-into-the-close-queue-and-age-out-questions "feature request at MSO")

Answer (score 4):

This seems somewhat wrong-headed; folks with this privilege level already see the number of close votes *when they're viewing the question*, so this really only matters for folks who wouldn't otherwise be looking at questions.

Getting more of the folks interested in certain topics involved in moderating those topics is a great idea. Getting folks with *no* interest to view questions just to pile on the close votes is likely to just get more stuff closed with less regard to whether or not it needs it. There's no opportunity to vote *not* to close, so this really only encourages pile-on voting.

It's also just noise for the 3K+ folks who're just looking for a relevant question title.

Regarding your edit: you're going even further in the direction of, "let's get more people to review by rubbing everyone's faces in it, all the time, until they give up and click something." That's really not cool. Try to keep some perspective here: this is not such a big problem that fixing it requires getting in the way of everyone trying to use these sites for their intended purpose.

Comment: Would the same logic not apply to the queue itself; attract moderation attention to questions you might not necessarily wish to read. If anything its better than the queue because at least it's usually "in the area" of things you're interested in (unlike the unfiltered queue). The imbalance between close and leave open is a fair comment however and I’ve attempted to address that in an edit to the proposal.

Comment: Difference between taking someone who has gone out of their way to help moderate and asking them if something should be closed... and throwing up a flag that screams "come close this" to everyone passing by. We don't show flags on posts anymore because doing so had such a negative effect on people's behavior, but there's still a flag queue for those who care to look for it.