# Rearrange button order on Close Vote review

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review

Can we move the "Close" and "Do Not Close" buttons far, far away from each other?  I've been running through the Close Vote review, and of the ~30 reviews I've done today, I accidentally hit "Do Not Close" button when I wanted to close.

Could we, at the very least, move "Close" to the left (so it's on the end) of the button order?

Comment: Is the problem that you see the word "close" appear twice in quick succession? Would it help if we renamed "Do Not Close" to something like "Keep Open"? I think it makes a lot of sense to have the buttons next to each other since they are exact opposite actions, but eliminating confusion / accidentally pushing the wrong button is always a good thing.

Comment: The rename would also work, but I think that the most-used button should be on the end.  (That's the primary reason for my crainial short-circuit.  Dunno where I picked up the habit.)

Comment: Are "Do not close" and "Keep Open" actions that really do anything, or are they NO-OP's?  Because if they don't do anything, then the button should be labelled "Take no action."

Comment: @RobertHarvey The "Do not close" button does do something; if a question accumulates 3 "do not close" votes, it disappears from the queue.

Comment: Then I like "Keep Open." @Laura: Can you link to the reference for that?  I tried searching, but...

Comment: @RobertHarvey I don't think we've posted documentation about it yet (long overdue, I know - a blog or comprehensive MSO post detailing all this stuff about the review queue. We are planning to post one, promise!) David talks about it on the recently revived Stack Exchange podcast, though (around 10:50). http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/10/se-podcast-33-its-back/

Comment: The behavior is documented here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139834/what-exactly-happens-with-the-new-do-not-close @Robert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We do not have plans to reorder the buttons at this moment, but we have renamed the button from "Do Not Close" to "Leave Open". Hopefully this will eliminate some of the confusion.