# Rearrange button order in Suggested Edits review queue

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review, suggested-edits

There was an earlier suggestion to [rearrange the buttons in the closevote review queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151718/rearrange-button-order-on-close-vote-review) to prevent errant clicks.

I would suggest a similar thing (knowing the previous didn't get implemented for close votes) in the Suggested Edits queue.  The current order of buttons there is:

<kbd>Approve</kbd> <kbd>Reject</kbd> <kbd>Improve</kbd> <kbd>Skip</kbd>

Already twice today, I managed to mis-click on <kbd>Approve</kbd> when intending to <kbd>Reject</kbd>.  Having no confirmation or subsequent reason selection to make, my errant approvals were saved.

To remedy this, a better order might be:

<kbd>Approve</kbd> <kbd>Improve</kbd> <kbd>Skip</kbd> <kbd>Reject</kbd>

My (over?)thinking here is that:

- Approve and Reject are really unlikely to be confused in a wild click
- A mis-click between Approve & Improve will do no harm if taken to the Improve screen,
- and not a huge amount harm if Approved when intending to Improve.
- Between Improve & Skip an errant Improve can be backed out of
- An errant Skip just kicks it down the road...
- Between Skip & Reject, an errant click on Reject gives can be backed out of on the reject reason
- An errant click on Skip just kicks your intended rejection down the road to someone else.

To maintain consistency with all the other queues, <kbd>Skip</kbd> probably needs to remain the right-most button. This doesn't deviate much from what is above in effectiveness. What's most important is to separate the Approve and Reject actions, approvals have no secondary screen.

<kbd>Approve</kbd> <kbd>Improve</kbd> <kbd>Reject</kbd> <kbd>Skip</kbd>

Comment: The Skip button is *always* the right-most button in every queue, and it will always remain in that position for consistency. If you accidentally click the Skip button, you can always go back in your browser. The URLs change and your back button will get you to the previous review item. As long as it's still reviewable, you can still take action on it whether or not you clicked Skip.

Comment: @animuson That's what I originally had

Comment: what about switching `Improve` and `Reject`? That means we separate the `Approve` and `Reject` and the same 'non conflicts' as with your suggested order.

Comment: @WouterJ Yes, that's the bottom example above, keeping Skip on the right.

Comment: @meta.michael ah, sorry. I missed those because I thought they where tags...

Answer (score 1):

No. I don't think this would be a good idea. People who are used to the original system will be thrown off. Is this really a big enough problem to surprise countless reviewers, force them to adapt to a new arrangement, etc.?

Instead of rearranging the buttons because of this problem, we could put more space between buttons or add an "approve confirm."

This isn't really that big of a problem though. We already have a safeguard of 3 people having to approve. I think a bit more space would be nice, but not a complete rearrangement.

Comment: I have ~1400 edit reviews, and this has happened to me enough times (10 at least, 2 today) to have taken note.  I think the benefit of preventing misappropriated edit approvals is greater than the trouble caused to the small set of reviewers whose mousepad <--> pixel motor memory is so ingrained as to be inconvenienced by this. Like all the other interface changes we get around here, some will complain and then everyone will get used to it.  Adding a confirmation to approvals on the other hand, is just that much more work for reviewers.

Comment: @meta.michael `10 at least` That's less that 1% of your edits. Is that really much? Also, it takes 3 approve votes to approve, so there is a safeguard.

Comment: Sorry I actually have 1100 edit reviews and ~1400 CV reviews - mixed them up, but closer to 1% error rate by my apparently terrible mousing skills.