# Close vote disappeared on a question just as I closed it

Tags: support, vote-to-close

There is a question on PMSE that I've been watching. It's a shopping question. I planned to close it, but I wanted to give the community some time to catch it in the reviews and take action themselves, so I waited a few days.

I had the question open on my screen, and it had 1 close vote, which had been there for possibly 4 days. According to Jeff, [close votes expire after 4 days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/56614/155826). I'm not sure if this is accurate as I thought I read somewhere that it's based on views, but in this particular case, I can see in our review history that a 900+ rep user voted to close the question **2 days ago.**

When I went to cast my close vote, I noticed the modal window that shows what categories close voters voted in was blank, so I refreshed the screen, and the close vote was gone.

Since it was only 2 days, and the question really didn't get a lot of views, I'm wondering if it is a bug, or if I'm just missing something about how this process works. It doesn't make sense that a close vote would age away that fast.

- [The question](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/3949/vcs-issuetracking-ci-for-free)
- [Close Review History](https://pm.stackexchange.com/review/close/history)

[image: Close Vote Record]

Comment: As I understand it, if enough people click the *Do Not Close* button in the Review page on the question, the aging process for the close votes starts immediately.  See http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/139836

Comment: @RobertHarvey, I thought about that too, but between August 30th and today, the only review vote on that question is the 900 rep user two days ago to close. Our review history is pretty small. It's just a single page. ;)