# When a question was voted to Leave Closed, does it return to the Reopen Votes review queue after being edited?

Tags: support, review, edits

In some [closed] questions, an edit may not be enough to the community consider it to reopening, so it is voted to Leave Closed three times. Therefore, the question will no longer be on the Reopen Votes review queue.

If the question is edited after three Leave Closed votes, does it return to the Reopen Votes review queue?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161390/what-are-the-review-queues-and-how-do-they-work is the place I tried to find a clear answer to this.  I'm pretty sure that a closed question only gets one pass through the review queue.  If the queue supports closure then further edits are needed but they don't put it back into the review queue.

Comment: Half a decade ago [Shog9 said](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/152491/six-reopen-votes-cast-resulted-in-tie-with-question-remaining-closed?rq=1#comment438185_152492): "no stonewalling", I can't find anything more recent. I believe it gets a mod flag auto-generated after a few reopen cycles, but once kicked it needs to be manually reopened. An additional SO answer [from Cody Grey](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/383178/3648282) sheds more light on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the answer to this can be found at [How do you reopen a closed question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36415/how-do-you-reopen-a-closed-question):

> [Editing the body of a question within five days of closure](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/196078) will
>   also add it to the [Reopen Review queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/161391), where people with the the
>   ability to cast reopen votes will assess it. A question can only be
>   added to the Reopen Review queue [once per closure via editing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239443),
>   and if it's edited, reviewers will be shown a diff view of the edit by
>   default. For this reason, you should make sure that any edits after
>   closure should make clear why the question should be reopened. If you
>   or someone else makes a minor edit and doesn't follow up with a more
>   major edit, reviewers may only see the minor edit and thus disagree
>   with reopening, which may force you to resort to the next option [which is **Requesting on meta to reopen**].

which links through to:

[Shog9 answered this question on meta.SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/256572/):

> A question will only be enqueued once per closure via editing. It will be enqueued once per reopen vote *as long as* there are no outstanding reopen votes that've already triggered a review.

I conclude that if the question is edited after three Leave Closed votes, it will not return to the Reopen Votes review queue.