# Filter [review Close Votes] to the tags I marked interesting

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, tags, review, vote-to-close

The number of open close votes just reached over 100k and I've never seen it go down before. I tried a number of those, but a lot are about subjects I don't understand (for me that would eg be python, or .net). I cant rate those properly because most of the time I cant really understand what it is about.

My idea would be to make with the same principle as Stack Overflow has with the [Questions]  tab, the subjects with preferred tags get displayed. Those same tags could be used for close-reviewing, because I would actually be able to review them which makes it a lot more interesting than keep clicking skip.

Any thoughts about his?

(ps, first post on meta, not sure whether I did this correct)

*edit: This account only has 1 point at the moment, my Stack Overflow account is more active.*

---

**Edit after a comment:**
I've just noticed the filter. While this does about the same as I was thinking about, this is a passive method. My suggestion would be automatically filter on preferred tags

Comment: Actually you can filter tags.

Comment: Three by three - you can only filter for max 3 tags. And yes, do that.

Comment: Why do you have two accounts? You should only have one.

Comment: Because something went wrong trying to post on another site. And im only using SO, so fixing it seems a bit overkill. Maybe I'll fix it one of these days

Comment: **My suggestion would be automatically filter on preffered tags** [you mean something like this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/208335/221351)

Comment: Yes, exactly that. Too bad I cant upvote :) What should I do with this topic?

Comment: see also: [Automatically filter the Close Votes review queue to active tags for newbies](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/192108/automatically-filter-the-close-votes-review-queue-to-active-tags-for-newbies)

Comment: @Martijn http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts

Comment: @Martijn flag it as a duplicate of the other question.