# Do I have to flag a question that is wrongly marked as a duplicate by the new system?

Tags: discussion, flags, duplicate-questions

There's this new mechanism to detect duplicates that brings up a box like that:

> This question may already have an answer here:
>   Incredible question **4 answers**

Today I found a question that fooled me at first too. But it is not a duplicate and therefore  marked falsely: "[How do you detect when CSS animations start and end with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14796936/1456376)".

My question is: How to unmark a question like this?

- Do I have to flag it? That would actually mean more work for all moderators as this may not be solved as easy as a violating comment for example.
- Wouldn't it be nice to have something like a vote for "Marked correctly?" It could work like a close vote. So at least five users have to check "*no*" to remove it?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125/how-about-a-vote-not-to-close-option-to-counter-the-vote-to-close

Comment: Another example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14792931/java-regex-split-comma-separated-list-but-exclude-commas-within-parentheses

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> My question is: How to unmark a question like this?

You don't. This message does not indicate that it is a duplicate, but that it might be. So far one user thinks it might be one. That's all.

> Do I have to flag it?

No. This is all part of the community moderation process. There is nothing wrong here. If no other users agree that this is a duplicate, at some point the vote will expire and disappear. There is no need for moderator intervention, nor can a moderator be reasonably expected to do anything about this.

> Wouldn't it be nice to have something like a vote for "Marked correctly?" It could work like a close vote. So at least five users have to check "no" to remove it?

That sort of exists. As part of the review queues, users have the ability to vote to leave the question opened when it appears within the close vote queue. As [explained here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/139836/161198), if a sufficient number of users click the button, *"the question will be immediately removed from the queue (not shown to any more reviewers) and the ageing starts immediately"*.

I personally don't particularly like these new banners. I think they are somewhat misleading and have found they give far more importance to my single close vote than I want to attach to it (or at least that's my perception). But it's a single vote and the question is not closed. Nothing needs to happen here.

Comment: Thanks for your brief explanation. "*If no other users agree that this is a duplicate, at some point the vote will expire and disappear.*" is very interesting and I didn't know about that by now. I also think that even though it's a nice mechanism it could lead people to not read the question briefly as soon as they see the little box.

Comment: That last issue is part of my problem with it as well. But perhaps that's still caused by me being used to such a box indicating that the question is actually closed. Maybe that will fade over time. "CHANGE CONFUSING. HULK SMASH!". ;)

Comment: The 'Leave Closed' votes do not make close votes expire any faster. The only effect 'Leave Closed' votes have is that the question is removed from the review queue if enough people vote that way. Once removed from the queue, the resulting lack of attention for the question does usually mean the close vote expires naturally.

Comment: @MartijnPieters "Leave Open". But ignoring that, are you entirely sure? I seem to remember that they do have that effect. I'll remove it for now.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that, I meant "Leave Open". I can't find the reference right now, but that's what I've seen here on meta before, as explained by the devs.

Comment: Ah, bingo: [What exactly happens with the new "Do Not Close"?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139834) We are both somewhat right; the minimal views requirement for expiring votes is removed when we vote "Leave Open".

Comment: @MartijnPieters Ah, haha, teamwork. I'll update

Comment: +1 for *"I think they are somewhat misleading and have found they give far more importance to my single close vote than I want to attach to it"*. I posted a comment on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14792931/211627) explaining the "duplicate" was not a duplicate (which at least two other members agreed with), but the question has received 2 additional close votes since then.

Comment: I have long suspected that close votes, after the first one, are governed by crowd behaviour, not individual judgement.