# How does reviewing influence closing?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, vote-to-close, review-abuse

Consider a [question that has been marked as duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15456014/what-does-the-symbol-mean-in-prolog-when-dealing-with-lists) for no good reason. The [indicated duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6635451/testing-prolog-difference-lists) uses the notion *difference list* in the title. But there is no more commonality than that.

After being marked, the question [was reviewed](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/1733512). 3 Leave Open, and 2 Close whose tags are entirely unrelated.

Still, the closing button still shows (2/5). How does the process continue? How long is this left like this? Is it still possible to further review the question by others? Or is the question now waiting for further close votes?

The general answer [What is a "closed", “on hold”, or "duplicate" question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10582/what-is-a-closed-question) does not mention reviewing. Maybe this is intended.

Comment: you can find your answer here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139834/what-exactly-happens-with-the-new-do-not-close

Comment: Short answer: the close votes will age away, but it's not immediate.