# What happens when a moderator clicks 'leave open' in the close-vote queue?

Tags: support, review, vote-to-close, moderators, binding-vote

It takes [3 ordinary users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139834/what-exactly-happens-with-the-button-leave-open-previously-do-not-close) clicking "leave open" in the close-vote queue to remove the question from the queue.

How about diamond mods?

Do they remove it from the queue in one click, or not?

Comment: A moderator action always completes review, no matter what the action is (except skip of course).

Comment: @animuson and what happens if a moderator fails an audit? He/she lose his/her diamond on spot? :-)

Comment: @Shadow Do mods even *get* audits?

Comment: @Scimonster why not? It's showing to anyone who review.

Comment: @Scimonster We do. And occasionally we *do* fail those bad ones that pop up in the Close/Reopen queues.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

When a moderator clicks "leave open", the review is marked completed and the question is removed from the queue. The existing close votes on the question [start aging away](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136989/how-do-close-votes-age-away/166124#166124), but are not immediately cleared.

Comment: So, as a Mod, leaving the desicion to the community you need to click skip or leave the page?!

Comment: @Ben Mod is expected to think along with community :) That's for all the mod actions. Their decisions are binding... (Sorry for being a bit late :D)

Comment: And all recommended closure flags are declined.