# Specify that three "Leave Open" votes are required in the Help Center

Tags: feature-request, review, help-center

From Help Center > Privileges > cast close and reopen votes:

> Edits or a **sufficient number of "Leave Open" reviews** will remove the question from review and immediately begin aging the close votes.

I want to suggest to specify that:

> three(3) "Leave Open" reviews will remove the question from review and immediately begin aging the close votes.

Comment: Not sure but isn't it a little more complex than that, I thought for instance a sequence like c-lo-c-lo-c-lo would leave it on the queue a bit longer? But a link or description of how it works exactly would be good.

Comment: @PeterJ: It's always three for that particular review task. If the task is completed without closing the question, or if it's closed, reopened, and flagged/voted to close again, the new task will start over and need three more Leave Open actions to finish that way.

Comment: Presumably the idea is to allow for different sites to customize the number of LO actions needed, but I'm not aware that any sites actually do that, and it's a bit misguided anyway to just leave a placeholder instead of putting in the actual number.

Comment: For the record, the [tag:voting] tag is for upvotes and downvotes, for anything that is related to review, we have the [tag:review] tag.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps a link could be provided from the Help to [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/139836/215590) to [What exactly happens with the button "Leave Open" (previously "Do Not Close")?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139834/what-exactly-happens-with-the-button-leave-open-previously-do-not-close)

> Normally, a question must hit 100 views before close votes age away,
>   so as to give enough folks time to see and review it. Questions with
>   close votes stay in the review queue until they are closed or the
>   votes expire.
>
> But if enough people (currently 3) select "Do Not Close" within the
>   review queue, the question will be immediately removed from the queue
>   (not shown to any more reviewers) and the aging starts immediately.

Alternatively, with a little more detail added, [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161390/what-are-the-review-queues-and-how-do-they-work/161391#161391) to [What are the review queues, and how do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161390/what-are-the-review-queues-and-how-do-they-work) could be used but it currently seems to fall similarly short on detail:

> Finally, you can also choose Leave Open (or Leave Closed in the reopen
>   queue). What does this last option do? If enough people vote to leave
>   a question open or closed, the question is removed from the
>   close/reopen queue (respectively) and immediately begins aging the
>   existing close or reopen votes on the question (it does not clear
>   them).