# Could we split up revision queues to get counts closer to zero?

Tags: discussion, review

One of the really clever little aspects of the review tab is that it shows the number of posts in the queue, giving people some psychological incentive to work on it in order to make it reach zero. With the suggested edit queue's single-digit count, it seems to be a quite effective trick.

The problem is the two other counters. The closed votes queue, seems to be stuck at its current 58-59k mark, and many of the close votes regard year-old posts which quite frankly would better be left to rest in peace.

Could it not be tweaked or split up so "hot" close votes for new(ish) questions could be brought to a more manageable size?

Then people who are interested could have a 50k-sized queue of questions from 2009 (which no one has touched since) and mull over the question if they should be closed or not.

The low-quality posts are slightly different, as they are slowly, but steadily being worked through, even if it means that the community has to mull over thousands of long-forgotten posts.

Also in this case the queue could be split, so year-old forgettable answers to forgettable questions can just be, well, forgotten in a queue all of their own - so people don't have to wade through them, one by one in search of some gem to rescue.

This would make it realistic for users to help bring relevant revision queue counts to zero, and that gives a warm and fuzzy feeling.

Comment: Personally I'd like to see a [votes about to expire](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/113056/153020) task in /review - that would have much smaller numbers for sensible time periods. Actions could be close or expedite expiry.

Comment: @Flexo That's not a bad idea, actually. "Vote to close now, or forever hold your peace".

Comment: the problem has been (at last) acknowledged and addresed by SE team: [Enough fuzzying: let's let everything into the close queue and age out questions that don't reach a threshold](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252584/enough-fuzzying-lets-let-everything-into-the-close-queue-and-age-out-questions "feature request at MSO")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The close-vote queue is probably stuck because people are wading through the low-quality queue (in which a lot of posts are close-worthy). The low-quality queue is shrinking at a fast pace and will be empty pretty soon.

I think we should stop worrying about the close-vote queue until that time and see if it starts shrinking.

I personally think it is really nice to keep modding old questions. Since this is a Q&A site, not a forum, topics will keep existing a long time (unlike forums where usually only the latest topics are relevant and the old ones are left to rot). I think we should value old questions as well and try making *the entirety* of the Q&A database valuable and relevant. This includes closing and possibly deleting all crap questions, even old ones.

Comment: Yeah, I see that the close votes queue is shrinking now, so you are probably right. It will take a lot of time, though, but maybe that is not really an issue.

Answer (score 6):

I have a better idea.

Lets make a commitment. Starting today, lets all review at least 50 (or until close votes are depleted).

With 60000 questions and 5 close votes per question, it takes 300000 actions. If 100 users, join in, we can do this in 2 months.

Comment: `If 100 users, join in, we can do this in 2 months.` Only if we stop accepting questions for two months.

Comment: At least we could remove the backlog.

Comment: I guess my problem with that idea is that I don't really see the point of working a hundred people for two months in order to close questions that nobody is going to change or answer anyway. Which I believe is the case with most of those old questions in the queue.

Comment: Funny thing is someone suggested exactly this in November: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111734/26-000-questions-have-close-votes-now-what/113056#comment289891_111735